# C++ Eigen - Cannot run SVD due to "maxCoeff()" error

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have the following code

```
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> S = A*B.transpose();
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> svd(S);
```

Which has an error when calculating the SVD with both JacobiSVD and BDCSVD

```
/eigen-src/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h: In instantiation of 
‘Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>& 
Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::compute(const MatrixType&,
 unsigned int) [with _MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>; int 
 QRPreconditioner = 2; MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>]’:

/eigen-src/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:548:14:   required from 
‘Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::JacobiSVD(const 
MatrixType&, unsigned int) [with _MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
 int QRPreconditioner = 2; MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>]’
/eigen-src/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:676:40: error: 
‘const Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >::CwiseAbsReturnType’ 
{aka ‘const class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<double>, const
 Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >’} has no member named ‘maxCoeff’
  676 |   RealScalar scale = matrix.cwiseAbs().maxCoeff();**
```

I have no idea why it fails for my matrix, why isn't maxCoeff() defined? I'm too new too Eigen to understand.

Comment: Does `matrix.array().abs()` do any better?

Comment: SVD is designed for dense matrices, not sparse. As I understand it, for sparse matrices you use the [iterative linear solvers](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__IterativeLinearSolvers__Module.html)

Comment: Thanks! This should be the answer @Homer512

Comment: @TimRoberts The issue here is more that `JacobiSVD` does only work for dense matrices, but does not show this directly but only fails because it uses methods on the matrix, which are not implemented for sparse matrices. (`maxCoeff` would actually not be too hard to implement for sparse matrices).

Comment: I don't really have code to show. A single line is not a proper answer. There is no 1-to-1 replacement for SVD. If all you need is solving a system and one of the solvers works for your style of matrix, feel free to extend your question to cover your use case and post an answer with workable code. But my experience with Eigen's Sparse module is too limited to simply write "do this instead". I would just copy-and-paste the documentation

Comment: I agree with Homer, the solution depends on what you actually need. If you need the singular values, you may need to convert your matrix to a dense matrix first. Or check if there are other libraries which can calculate (or approximate) singular values directly from sparse matrices.